# Twilio quickstart immediately disconnects on call

Tags: javascript, twilio

I'm following Twilio's quickstart guide, and I managed to set up a TwiML App, the Twilio Function, and the local server to handle the app (which is the part I'm interested in).

So, the thing is, I input my own phone number in the small box, so I can try to call myself using a Twilio Phone Number, but when the call is started it is also immediately rejected.

The events can be seen in the page as:

```
Successfully established call!
Call ended.
```

Is there a trick to keep the call up?

Comment: pretty sure you have to verify any number you are calling while you're in trial mode (assuming that's what you're using)

https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-to-use-your-free-trial-account#verify-your-personal-phone-number

Comment: Not using trial, and there's a verified phone there (not mine).

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled International Permissions for the number you are trying to call? Have you entered the number you are dialing in E.164 format? Also, take a look at your console debugger and the Request Inspector for additional insights into the issue.

How to protect your account from toll fraud with Voice Dialing Geo Permissions

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/03/how-to-protect-your-account-from-toll-fraud-with-voice-dialing-geo-permissions.html

E.164

https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-e164

Twilio Debugging Tools:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/debugging-tools

Debugging your Twilio Application:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/debugging

Comment: Would I need to enable International Permissions for a number bought in the same area as my phone number? That doesn't make any sense! I'll check the E.164 formatting later though. In the debug console nothing shows up.